# How to merge low frequency data with high frequency data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to merge a low frequency dataframe with a high frequency dataframe. I want the low frequency data to show up in each row of the new data frame. For example 2018-01-01 has 1 value in the low frequency data. For each hour of that day in the high frequency dataframe, that one value should show up. Here is what I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime

low_freq = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods = 30, freq='D'))
low_freq['DateTime'] = 
    [datetime.strptime(str(i), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in low_freq[0]]
low_freq.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
low_freq['col1'] = np.random.randint(5, size=len(low_freq))
low_freq = low_freq.iloc[:,1:]

high_freq = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=24*30, freq='H'))
high_freq['DateTime'] = 
    [datetime.strptime(str(i), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in high_freq[0]]
high_freq.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
high_freq['col1'] = np.random.random(len(high_freq))
high_freq = high_freq.iloc[:,1:]

high_freq['low_freq_val'] = 
[low_freq[low_freq.index == i.index.date() for i in high_freq.index]
```

Comment: You should look for on how to upsample the low frequency data to match the high frequency data

Comment: Do the datasets span the same exact range time range, and are the timespans always fully sampled? If so, then `concat` + `ffill` is simple.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).ffill()` won't work in this situation because I don't want there to be any potential for a low_freq value ending up in a date it doesn't belong. The forward fill could push a value forward onto the next date.